# Orientation issue in XCode 4.5.2 GM Seed version with iOS 6

Tags: iphone, ios, ios6, xcode4.5

I am working on iPhone application with both Portrait orientations support (Portrait and Portrait UpsideDown).

In earlier XCode4.5.1, I have resolved this issue by:

- Setting rootViewController in AppDelegate
- Mentioning shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation like this:

  ```
  -(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:    (UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation {

       return UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(toInterfaceOrientation);   }
  ```
- Mentioning supportedInterfaceOrientation in info.plist file

Now I am doing the same things for newer XCode but in iPhone simulator v6.0 its not supporting rotation properly.

I have tried with these methods as well:

```
-(BOOL) shouldAutorotate {

  BOOL returnValue = NO;

  int interface =  [self preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation];

  if(UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(interface)) {

    // Code to handle portrait orientation
    returnValue = YES;
  }
  else {

    // Code to handle Landscape orientation
    returnValue = NO;
  }

  return returnValue;
}

- (NSUInteger) supportedInterfaceOrientations {

  return (UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait | UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
{
  return (UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait |
          UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
}
```

Please guide me how to support both the Portrait orientations for iOS > 4.3 all the versions.

Thanks in advance,
Mrunal

Comment: I am also having a problem that started with XCode 4.5.2 - in 4.5.1 my rotation in iOS 6 worked normally, after upgrading to 4.5.2 my view controllers appear in the wrong rotation and then animate into the right one.  Super frustrating, will be uninstalling and trying to find a way back to 4.5.1.  Shoddy work, Apple!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Why Did Orientation Change to Landscape Stop Working in iOS 6?***

Starting in IOS 6.0 there are several orientation changes that stopped my app from rotation out of Portrait.
The fix for me, and the one applicable here, is that you must `setRootViewController` on the window in your AppDelegate. The earlier answer offers several suggestions that are all correct, but misses the one item that was relevant for me.

In `application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`, after:

```
[window makeKeyAndvisible]
```

or

```
[window addSubview: viewController.view];
```

You must replace with:

```
if([[UIDevice currentDevice].systemVersion floatValue] >= 6.0) {
    [window setRootViewController:viewController];
} else {
    [window addSubview: viewController.view];
    (or [window makeKeyAndvisible])
}
```

You also need to add the new `shouldAutoRotate` instead of the depreciated `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation`, but this was easier to find and less crucial for me.

Same with making sure all your orientations are specified in your .plist file.

I did not need to override `supportedInterfaceOrientations` because I am satisfied with the default orientations (all for iPad `UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll`, all but upside-down for iPhone `UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown`).

Answer (score 0):

I have to admit, that when iOS 6 came around, I fiddled around with this until I got something to work, and then stopped.  But, here is my guess:

I believe that `shouldAutorotate` is intended to be used in situations when you might want to **dynamically** change whether or not your app supports autorotation at all.  I don't think it's intended for you to tell iOS **which** orientations you support (like the original `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:` method).  So, if your app supports **any** autorotation, I think you should just do this:

```objc
-(BOOL) shouldAutorotate {
   return YES;
}
```

`supportedInterfaceOrientations` is where you are supposed to identify **which** orientations you support.

However, in that method, you're doing that differently than what I've been using (which might, or might not be a problem).  I think you should use [the *mask* constants](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006728-CH3-DontLinkElementID_62), for this method.  So, instead of this:

```objc
- (NSUInteger) supportedInterfaceOrientations {

   return (UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait | UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
}
```

use this:

```objc
- (NSUInteger) supportedInterfaceOrientations {

   return (UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortraitUpsideDown);
}
```

Also, I don't think the `preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation` method is supposed to return more than one orientation.  *Preferred* should probably just be one, such as:

```objc
- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
{
  return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
}
```

[Here is the relevant Apple documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/RespondingtoDeviceOrientationChanges/RespondingtoDeviceOrientationChanges.html)

**Update:**

The other thing you might try is using this method:

```objc
- (NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window {
    return (UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortraitUpsideDown);
}
```

in your App Delegate class.  This method is optional, but can set the default values for which orientations your app supports, in case you don't specify them in all your View Controllers, or in the app's `plist` file.  Since you don't show your `plist` file, and your other View Controllers, I can't tell if this might help, or not.  But, it might be something to try.

Comment: I have made those changes but still its not working, at initial it calls supportedInterfaceOrientations method only, no other methods get called. And still orientation is not getting changed when i rotate simulator. I am not getting what could be the issue.

Comment: @mrunal, I added one more thing to try (see my **Update** above).  if you've done all these things (together), and it still doesn't work, then I'm not sure what's going wrong.